# Disable New Ubuntu Desktop Installer On Live Image

Tags: live-usb, live-cd, custom-distributions

Does anyone know how to make a 23.10 live disk boot straight to the desktop without prompting to install? I know how to do it with `ubiquity`, but `ubuntu-desktop-installer` doesn't appear to use boot arguments.